# changing the computer name on a IIS 7

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2008

Are there any issues in regards to IIS that result from changing the computer name on a IIS 7 server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS7 (Windows 2008) Does not have the same issue with the userids that IIS6 (Windows 2003) had.  You can safely rename your web server.

Answer (score 1):

i ve been searching for a while and found the following useful

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/31184520/cannot-access-iis-web-server-after-computer-name-change.aspx

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/234142